# Set subtitles font size on facet charts in Altair

Tags: python, altair

How can I edit the font size of the years appearing above each subgraph in the [example](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/us_population_over_time_facet.html) below:
Take from the altair gallery

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.population.url

alt.Chart(source).mark_area().encode(
    x='age:O',
    y=alt.Y(
        'sum(people):Q',
        title='Population',
        axis=alt.Axis(format='~s')
    ),
    facet=alt.Facet('year:O', columns=5),
).properties(
    title='US Age Distribution By Year',
    width=90,
    height=80
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set this using `labelFontSize` in the `header` property of the `facet` encoding:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.population.url

alt.Chart(source).mark_area().encode(
    x='age:O',
    y=alt.Y(
        'sum(people):Q',
        title='Population',
        axis=alt.Axis(format='~s')
    ),
    facet=alt.Facet(
        'year:O', columns=5,
        header=alt.Header(labelFontSize=20)
    ),
).properties(
    title='US Age Distribution By Year',
    width=90,
    height=80
)
```

[image]

For the full list and description of available header properties, see https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.Header.html